# Is There Workaround for Using a Bearer Token as Authentication for Declarative Named Credential?

Tags: visual-workflow, namedcredentials, external-services

My OpenApi 3.0 schema requires just a bearer token as authentication. Salesforce **declarative** Named Credential does not offer this as option. When using Password Authentication with a dummy username I understandably get a `404 Authentication Error`.

Is there some kind of workaround using one of the supplied methods such as:

- JWT
- JWT Token Exchange
- Oauth 2.0

that might be used as a workaround to avoid this error? The Salesforce PM responded in their portal stating an option for this is "on the roadmap"; however this is not helpful for today. The [External Services Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enhanced_external_services_considerations.htm&type=5) state that

> The standard HTTP request
> headers Accept, Content-Type, and Authorization are handled by the
> External Service and can't be overridden as OpenAPI operation input
> parameters. The Authorization header is set by the Named Credential.

Apex Named Credential would likely work; however this cannot be used with the **declarative** External Services which we are using in this case.

Comment: Where does your token come from?

Comment: Is calling api without named creds an option (that you make a direct non-named creds api call and set the Auth header)?

Comment: The provider of API just gives us the token, like a username. We can refresh it at will via their UI.
Salesforce does not let us set the Auth header in the schema per their documentation (quoted above).

Comment: The API key style of token acquisition workflow doesn't fit NC/Ext Svcs. Your only option is to route the request through your own middleware (which could be a [Function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/index.html)) that will act as a proxy and rewrite the headers to add the token.